# Calling a class method on a dict object: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'get_keyval'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, inheritance

Is it possible to get the key value of the `filter_dict` object kind of that `filter_dict.get_keyval("author")`?:

```
import json

class Config(dict):
    def open_json_file(self, json_string):
        load_dict = json.loads(json_string)
        return load_dict

    def get_keyval(self, key):
        search_key = self.load_dict.get(key)
        return search_key

filter_dict = Config().open_json_file('{"author" : "Steve", "author_email" : ""}')
print(filter_dict.get_keyval("author"))
```

Getting:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'get_keyval'
```

Did the following workaround (but that is not what i want):

```
import json

class Config():
    def open_json_file(self, json_string):
        load_dict = json.loads(json_string)
        return load_dict

    def get_keyval(self, json_string, key):
        search_key = json_string.get(key)
        return search_key

filter_dict = Config().open_json_file('{"author" : "Steve", "author_email" : ""}')
print(Config().get_keyval(filter_dict, "author"))
```

Comment: You're not using class methods correctly.  You do *not* want to create a new class instance each time you call a class method - that's insane.  In this case, you don't even want a class method, you want a static method.  So add the `@staticmethod` decorator and then invoke the method without calling the constructor.

Comment: Why do you need those methods in the first place? You are just wrapping functionality of existing objects. `filter_dict = json.loads('...')` and `print(filter_dict.get("author"))` is equivalent, without requiring a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the object returned by `Config().open_json_file` is not `Config`, but the plain dict returned by `json.loads`. Basically, `Config` is not a class, but just a collection of functions coded as methods. What you want is probably this:

```
import json

class Config(dict):  # derive from dict to gain get and constructor
  @classmethod
  def from_json_file(cls, json_string):
    """Initialize Config dict from a JSON string"""
    load_dict = json.loads(json_string)
    return cls(load_dict)  # create new Config (dict) filled with JSON content

  def get_keyval(self, key):
    return self.get(key)

filter_dict = Config.from_json_file(...)
print(filter_dict.get_keyval("author"))  # you might want to just call plain filter_dict.get("author") here
```

Comment: also note that just doing `get_keyval = dict.get` in the class definition would be enough to create an alias to the method.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen for my example you're right but i have a much bigger json-file and i want to search the dict-object for the key and returning its value.